# How to stop the Left Scroll animation as the text in the div element completes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have created the horizontal animation effect and works fine on `click` event of forward and backward buttons.

The issue is here I am unable stop the scrolling  effect. The horizontal scroll continues on clicking of button after the text in the `div` element completes. I want to restrict the scrolling effect and should not scroll after as soon as text in the `div` is completed.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shas__g/6r3h2t8z/1/) of the template:

```js
$(function() {
  scrollBar();
});

function scrollBar() {
  var imageWidth = 300;
  var $elmt = $("div.container");
  $('#fwdBtn').click(function() {
    $elmt.find('div.title-holder a').animate({
      left: "-=" + imageWidth
    }, 5000);
  })

  $('#bwdBtn').click(function() {
    $elmt.find('div.title-holder a').animate({
      left: "+=" + imageWidth
    }, 5000);
  })
}
```

```css
h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 8%;
}

.textArea {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.textArea span {
  color: red;
}

div.container {
  width: 90%;
}

div.title-holder {
  width: 90%;
  background: silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

div.title-holder a {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 0px;
}

#fwdBtn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  top: 11%;
}

#bwdBtn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 11%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3> Week 1 Template </h3>
  <div class="textArea">
    <p> <span>Click</span> the Forward button to move up and <span>Click</span> the Back button to move back. <span>Click</span> the title of the work to view the work of art and description </p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-holder">
      <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward" id="fwdBtn"></button>
  <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward" id="bwdBtn"></button>
</div>
```

Thanks for the suggestions in prior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the animation when the text is in `viewport`.

Here is the js fiddle for the same:
https://jsfiddle.net/jjxLqL4w/